# How to limit FK choices based on kwargs input in Django for a form

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have a form which is for creating a booking slot. In the booking slot model there is a foreign key model to the location for that slot.

```
#forms.py
class BookingSlotForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BookingSlot
        fields = ['date','start_time', 'end_time', 'location']


#views.py
class CreateBookingForm(CreateView):
    template_name = 'app_book/create_bookings.html'
    form_class = BookingSlotForm


#urls.py
urlpatterns =[path('create/<int:club>/', CreateBookingForm.as_view(), name="create_booking")]
```

I want to be able to use the club id (given in the URL) to limit the choices for locations for a booking slot. For example, a club called Lambda can only see courts 4, 5 and 6 and not courts 2, 3 or 1. I have looked into "limit_choices_to" but I don't think this is the right way to do this. Help would be much appreciated

Edit:
Here is my models.py

```
class BookingSlot(models.Model):
    start_time = models.TimeField("Start Time")
    end_time = models.TimeField("End Time")
    date = models.DateField("Date")
    location = models.ForeignKey(Court, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Here is my model for location (called Court)

```
class Court(models.Model):
    court_name = models.CharField("Court Name", max_length=100)
    club = models.ForeignKey(Club, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Can you share the `BookingSlot` model? Does this have a `ForeignKey` to the `club`?

Comment: class BookingSlot(models.Model):
    start_time = models.TimeField("Start Time")
    end_time = models.TimeField("End Time")
    date = models.DateField("Date")
    location = models.ForeignKey(Court, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Comment: please [edit] the question.

Comment: edited it into the question there cheers

Comment: But how is the `Location` related to the `club`?

Comment: I added another edit there. The location has a FK to the club, hope that clarifies things

Comment: @DavidDunne, If answer of Willem Van Onsem or any other answer, helped solve your problem, please mark it as accepted. See [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can override the logic of the method that will intialize the `BookingSlotForm`:

```
class BookingSlotForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, club=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if club is not None:
            self.fields['location'].queryset = Location.objects.filter(
                club_id=club
            )

    class Meta:
        model = BookingSlot
        fields = ['date','start_time', 'end_time', 'location']
```

Then we pass the value for the `club` to the form by overriding `get_form_kwargs`:

```
class CreateBookingForm(CreateView):
    template_name = 'app_book/create_bookings.html'
    form_class = BookingSlotForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['club'] = self.kwargs['club']
        return kwargs
```